# AWS: My domain is still pointing to a deleted bucket

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I created a bucket that I had my domain point to and I decided to delete the bucket and have my domain point to a wordpress instance instead. The documentation is very clear on how to update your hosted zone and have the domain point to the instance but for some reason my domain is still pointing to:

> example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I read my hosted zone details and it says this:

> - Before the Domain Name System will start to route queries for this domain to Route 53 name servers, you must update the name server records either with the current DNS service or with the registrar for the domain, as applicable. For more information, click the ? icon above.

Okay very clear what I need to do.

Not much help but my name server records are updated at both the instance and record set, My elastic IP in the record Set Type A is the same as my AWS instance. I can access the elastic ip of my website as well.

I am sure I am overlooking something small, but I am out of troubleshooting ideas. So any help on how to have my domain point to my AWS instance will be greatly appreciated.

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

EDITED: When I type in www.example.com it redirects me to

> example.com..s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

```
404 NOT found
Code: NOSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName:
Requstid:
HostId:
```

[Record Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSouI.png)

Comment: You should not have had to modify any name server records at all. Did you just move your domain to Route53 or something? You should have only needed to modify the one CNAME or A record that was pointing to S3.

Comment: I did not modify the NS at all on the Route 53 Management --> Hosted Zone   section. I bought my domain through amazon. And I added an A record with my elastic IP. I can go to my wordpress site by directly typing in the IP but when I type in www.exmaple.com I get the following redirect to exmaple.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com:  <look at pics>

Comment: Then why did you include all that name server stuff in your question? What is the TTL set to on the A record, and what was it previously set to? Did you try clearing the DNS cache on your local computer?

Comment: TTL is 300. And You are right, DNS cache was the issue!!!!I I knew it was something simple. Thanks a lot Mark. i just spit 4 hours yesterday trying to figure out what I did wrong #learnwhiletroubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Probably cached by the DNS server you are using. Depending on your TYL, DNS servers will cache the mapping. For example, if you have TTL 3600, it could take an hour to update. Read [this AWS forum question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=342266).

Comment: No I don't think that is the issue, Its been like this for the past 24 hours. But does my logic behind my troubleshooting sound good? I will recheck everything again.